# If lspci command shows nothing, how to check GPU is cuda-capable or not?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, cuda

From the [CUDA documents](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-metas), I need to check whether my computer is capable by using the command:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

but for my Thinkpad, this returns nothing. The document further says

> If you do not see any settings, update the PCI hardware database that Linux maintains by entering update-pciids (generally found in /sbin) at the command line and rerun the previous lspci command.

I just don't understand what this means, who can tell me what to do next?

Ps, this is my computer:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64
Host: 4291RF4 ThinkPad X220
Kernel: 4.15.0-24-generic 
Uptime: 2 hours, 18 mins 
Packages: 3252 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: Xfce 
WM: Xfwm4 
WM Theme: Greybird 
Theme: Greybird [GTK2], Radiance [G 
Icons: Elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2 
Terminal: terminator 
CPU: Intel i3-2310M (4) @ 2.100GHz 
GPU: Intel Sandybridge Mobile 
Memory: 2265MiB / 7859MiB
```

Comment: You don't have an Nvidia adapter.

Comment: `lspci` doesn't "show nothing". You can run `lspci` and see what PCI devices are installed. The `grep -i nvidia` filters `nvidia` output. In your case you don't have any Nvidia device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA is only available on Nvidia cards. Check list of CUDA capable graphics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). You have Intel GPU - try [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) instead of CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling to run the command `update-pciids` from the command line.

> ```
> update-pciids(8)               The PCI Utilities              update-pciids(8)
>
> NAME
>        update-pciids - download new version of the PCI ID list
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        update-pciids [-q]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        update-pciids  fetches the current version of the pci.ids file from the
>        primary distribution site and installs it.
> ```

You will need to run it as root (`sudo update-pciids`) in order to write the updated file.

**HOWEVER** it most likely won't make any difference - as far as I know, the X220 has only Intel integrated graphics. Historically, Thinkpads with discrete graphics have been denoted by a "p" suffix.